# ¿Cómo crear dos variables a partir de un string que está separado por espacios?

Tags: c++

La consigna es esta:

> Se dispone de un archivo de textos donde cada línea contiene 2 strings con
> nombres y apellidos de personas, pero en algunos casos se ubica primero el nombre y en otros el
> apellido, aunque el apellido siempre está en mayúsculas (todas sus letras. no así el nombre). Hay un
> solo nombre por persona y no hay apellidos dobles ni compuestos. Escriba una clase que posea: a) un
> constructor que reciba el nombre de un archivo de texto y almacene las líneas del archivo en un vector
> de la STL.: primero el apellido y luego el nombre

Cómo podría hacer para verificar cuál de las dos partes del string es el apellido y de ahí insertar primero el apellido y luego el nombre en el vector? Traté de plantearlo, pero no pude. Adjunto lo que va del código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

bool isUpper(const string& s) {
    return all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), [](unsigned char c){ return std::isupper(c); });
}

string verificacion(string s) {
    for(auto x : s) {
        if(x == '') {
            if(isUpper(s) == true) {
                return s;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Manipula {
    string nomArch;
    vector<string>v;
public:
    Manipula(string nom) {
        nomArch = nom;
        ifstream arch(nomArch);
        string linea;
        char c;
        while(getline(arch, linea)) {
            if(c == '\n'){
                /*falta planteo*/
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Que es lo que se supone que hace `string verificacion(string)`?

Comment: Verifica si en el string hay una parte de la misma que contiene una palabra en mayúsculas, que vendría a ser un apellido.

Comment: Otra pregtuntita, el `if(x == '')` lo tienes asi o fue un error al copiar? Ademas de que ese codigo ni compila, ya que le faltan headers

Comment: En mi caso no compila porque no encuentra all_of, pero eso es un error del IDE. No tengo ningún otro error.

Comment: El all_of es de la libreria `algorithm`, de paso te falta el vector y string. Esa parte del codigo lo escribiste tu?

Comment: Ahí compila, por alguna razón mi IDE no encontraba el header para all_of. Sigo sin entender cómo proseguir con el problema.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116223/discussion-between-pablochaches-and-zilogz80).

Answer (score 0):

Para separar una cadena antes y después del espacio, puedes usar `std::getline` poniendo el espacio como separador:

```
char texto[]{"Hola mundo!"};
std::stringstream ss{texto};


std::string hola;
std::getline(ss, hola, ' ');

std::string mundo;
std::getline(ss, mundo);

std::cout << "Primer texto: " << hola << '\n'
    << "Segundo texto: " << mundo;
```

El código anterior [genera la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##bY6xCoMwFEXnvK94tYMKFjqrdO5Y6Nh2CDFoQF8kiVAQv90aqxSlU@Dce3KfaNuTqDmV43hUJOqukJgrbZ2RvLnAj9kVgSKHDVcUxdADExU36OTb6cerD6665th0VOhDMGTArCvSdDIVlV8fre3n9pTCJsdqclellK5WJCNrk5knGGIYZztjHvqnzMHOEbpzmOcY3Ixq5HJzioFnfsK/4ZNCYMy37rL0n2xqyx4wI11nCM8ZDOP4AQ):

> ```
> Primer texto: Hola
> Segundo texto: mundo!
> ```

Date cuenta que el caracter espacio es `' '` (hay un espacio entre cada comilla simple), **el caracter `''`** (ningún espacio entre cada comilla) **no existe**.

Sabido esto, sólo tienes que:

1. Leer línea a línea.
2. Leer palabra a palabra.
3. Comprobar cuál de las dos está toda en mayúsculas:

```
while (std::getline(archivo, linea))
{
    std::stringstream datos{linea};

    std::string izquierda;
    std::getline(datos, izquierda, ' ');

    std::string derecha;
    std::getline(datos, derecha);

    if (std::all_of(izquierda.begin(), izquierda.end(), [](unsigned char c) { return std::isupper(c); }))
        std::cout << "Apellido: " << izquierda << " Nombre: " << derecha << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "Apellido: " << derecha << " Nombre: " << izquierda << '\n';
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVDJTsMwED3XXzEKhyRSqTi3VSUqThyChMQBlQq59jSx5NjBdtiifHtIXNOFgrjZb94y81hVXTJJVd51F0IxWXOEudDWGaTlghwwew5RmWsjXHECMuY@KlwQIpSDkgqVpKQhI1ZQAw7fnV6tm/soWda5heVDlj2S5V12A7e0RJtG7YyQkXV8Ou3jhMp3oUANK8SrbrxBzzmmgBQK6aB7K4RESPwsRzfgSVCOd6w0JaN@mV8SOHXaNp7kdzhJEJ8vtUDD@5Qw@Lb3svGBMIYY4vTMgKPBvoG/5GG804ltOIFK@ay3yd57ssF8qPMoboKKD8BqndTKilwhB980S6EBg642CryZsHVVoUlYOoN2qCFswnTtYD6H6LpCKQXXU4iG/z7CDyHT5cZgmIV1h2f8pOLhKpQW//U80v1wPEkLnm1fRrjgakbarvsC)</kbd>.